# Compiling with Xcode cannot find <cstddef> and <cstdint> with C static linked library and header files

Tags: xcode

I have a precompiled statically linked C library, for which I attempting to create a wrapper for in Swift, which can be used in both macOS and iOS application. I have created a `module.modulemap` file and it can find my header which is good. However, when I try to "build" the C library, Xcode gives me the error `'cstddef' file not found`.

The solutions I have found so far would be to turn implementations files into objective-c, but as I already have a compiled library I cannot see what that should be needed. So can someone help me solve this issue?

I am using Xcode v9.2

Comment: I came up into this issue today. I am using XCode 12 and is really weird as if I clean the build it doesn't complain but the error come up after fully building the solution. @Lars Nielsen. Did you finally found any way to solve this issue?